# search an string array using given user and return indexes of the matched string array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array.

```
var possibleValues=["contacts","delete","new contact","add","display"];
```

user input can be "contacts" or "how to create a contact?".my function must return index as 0,2 which has a phrase contact in it.I am trying a logic but i cant find.What have i done currently is

```
var indexes = [];
for (i = 0; i < possibleValues.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].indexOf(userinput) != -1 || userinput.indexOf(arr[i])!=-1) {
    indexes.push(i);
  }
}
```

Someone can help me out in this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. But you have to compare with `-1`, not `1`. And you're using `arr[i]` instead of `possibleValues[i]`.

And if you want to match each word in the user input, you need to split it up, and add another nested loop.

```js
var possibleValues = ["contacts", "delete", "new contact", "add", "display"];
var userinput = "how to create contact";
var words = userinput.split(' ');
var indexes = [];
for (i = 0; i < possibleValues.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
    if (possibleValues[i].indexOf(words[j]) != -1 || words[j].indexOf(possibleValues[i]) != -1) {
      indexes.push(i);
      break;
    }
  }
}
console.log(indexes);
```

Comment: sorry i did mistake at the time of typing , but ur code doesnt give me the result for "how to create contact". can u pls help me in this issue

Comment: That doesn't match any of the possible values. What do you expect it to return?

Comment: It can't return `0`, because that has an `s` at the end of the word, but `how to create contact` doesn't.

Comment: i want the same output 0,2 because it contains contact in it

Comment: So you want to split up the user input into words, and compare each word to the possible values?